# Swift - function that does add one or more enum values to an array

Tags: swift, function, enums, append

Having a struct dat has a variable that may contain a array of one or more enum values.
I want with one function the possibility to add one or more enum values, like:

*mutating func addEnumValue(value: EnumValue ){}*

and

*mutating func addEnumValue(value: [EnumValue] ){}*

in one function.

I guess I need some overload or a special generiek...eh ...something.

```
enum LabelEnum: String {
// multiply possiblities posible
    case app
    case cond
    case title
    case block
    case none

    var id: String { self.rawValue }
}

struct LabelEnumModel: Identifiable {

    var id: Int
    var label: [LabelEnum]
    var description: String

    init(id: Int, label: LabelEnum = .none, description: String = "")
    {
        self.id = id
        self.label = [label]
        self.description = description
    }

    mutating func addLabel(_ label: LabelEnum ) {  // OR
    mutating func addLabel(_ label: [LabelEnum] ) {

    }


    mutating func clearLabel() {
        self.label = [.none]

    }
}
```

How can I do that? I did read or see ( YT ) this somewhere but don't remember where.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Variadic Parameters](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/functions/#Variadic-Parameters).

```
mutating func addLabel(_ labels: LabelEnum...) {
    for label in labels {
        self.label.append(label)
     }
 }
```

Comment: You also thank you, but what about, like above, when I get LabelEnums in brackets [ .cond, .block ]?

Answer (score 0):

Overloading is the keyword. This should work.

```
mutating func addLabel(_ labels: LabelEnum... ) {
    self.label.append(contentsOf: labels)
    print("addLabel1 - \(self.label)")
}

mutating func addLabel(_ labels: [LabelEnum] ) {
   // or 
   // self.label.append(contentsOf: labels)
   for label in labels {
       self.label.append(label)
   }
   print("label.addLabel 2 - \(self.label)")
}
```

Thanks to the posters about variadic code.
This way I can use it like:

```
label.addLabel(.title)
label.addLabel(.title, .cond)
label.addLabel([.title, .cond])
```

Comment: A side note, what I have seen before about this, was a different way to do it, but can't find it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would just have the one generic function:

```
    mutating func addLabel<S: Sequence>(_ labels: S) where S.Element == LabelEnum
    {
        self.labels.append(contentsOf: labels)
    }
```

And then use square brackets for single labels

```
m.addLabel([.block])
```

It's not really a huge overhead, probably. But you can always use `CollectionOfOne` if creating an array is too much overhead

```
m.addLabel(CollectionOfOne(.title))
```

However,

And I am not sure if I would ever recommend this, but you could turn your `enum` instances into collections.

There may be a use-case somewhere in the Universe where this is a good idea.

```
enum Label: String
{
    case app
    case cond
    case title
    case block
    case none
}

extension Label: Collection
{
    var startIndex: Int { 0 }
    var endIndex: Int { 1 }
    subscript(position: Int) -> Label { self }
    func index(after i: Int) -> Int { i + 1 }
}

struct Model
{
    var labels: [Label] = []

    mutating func addLabel<S: Sequence>(_ labels: S) where S.Element == Label
    {
        self.labels.append(contentsOf: labels)
    }
}

var m = Model()

m.addLabel([.block, .none])
m.addLabel(Label.cond)
m.addLabel(CollectionOfOne(.title))

print(m.labels.map({ $0.rawValue }))
// prints ["block", "none", "cond", "title"]
```